# How to make background image switching with page scroll? Any js or?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I saw on few websites that fantastic trick, when you scrol page,

background image scrolls up and above comes new one. I tryed search on google,

but i could not find anything. Does anyone know how to make it??? Please!

Comment: http://ianlunn.co.uk/plugins/jquery-parallax/ ?

Answer (score 0):

I think `parallax` is what you are looking for.

Comment: yes. i just typed scrolling... and that stuffs. thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

it can be done easily using jquery plugins, see this for example:

http://streetsmash.com/parallax-scrolling-plugins/